# How to integrate $\int\cos^4x\sin^2xdx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I was given the following problem to integrate: $$\int\cos^4x\sin^2x\ dx$$I am trying to integrate it using the double-angle identity, but I keep getting stuck. Here are my steps so far (numbered to make it clearer): 
\begin{align}
I&=\int\cos^4x\sin^2x\ dx \tag1
\\&=\int\left(\frac{1+\cos(2x)}{2}\right)^2\left(\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}\right)\ dx \tag2
\\&=\int\frac{(1+\cos(2x))(1-\cos^2(2x))}{8}\ dx \tag3
\\&=\int\frac{\left(1+\cos(2x)\right)\left(1-\frac{1+\cos(4x)}{2}\right)}{8}\ dx \tag4
\\&=\int\frac{(1+\cos(2x))(1-\cos(4x)}{16}\ dx \tag5
\\&=\int\frac{1-\cos^2(4x)}{16}\ dx \tag6
\end{align}

I would keep going and apply the double-angle identity to that last step, but something seems off to me. Is this the right track or am I missing something here? Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Paste this `integral(cos(x)^4 * sin(x)^2, x)` into this page https://sagecell.sagemath.org/ and press "Evaluate".

Comment: This is a tough integral. See [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+%28cos+x%29%5E4*%28sin+x%29%5E2)

Comment: $1-\cos^2(2x)=1-\dfrac{1+\cos(\color{red}4x)}2$

Comment: It's nothing tough though: there are well-known algorithms solving this kind of integrals. E.g. use this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_formula to translate it into an integration of rational functions, then decompose it into partial fractions etc.

Comment: These types of integrals are standard. [Paul](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/IntegralsWithTrig.aspx) has a page listing down exactly what to do when dealing with product of trigonometric functions.